# How to underline one text when hover over another text on css

Tags: html, css

I have a link with two texts so you can click any of them to execute the link. I want to be able to underline the first text when hover any of them. So far I've only been able to underline when hover the first one.

CSS:

```
.title:hover{
    text-decoration: underline
}
```

HTML:

```
<p:link href:...>
   <h:outputText styleClass="title" value="Title"/>
   <h:outputText styleClass="subtitle" value="Subtitle"/>
</p:link>
```

What CSS code I have to write in my `subtitle` class to be able to do that?

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-one-element-is-hovered

Comment: I can't post an answer, but this might do the trick. Below is your CSS:

`parent a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* prev siblings should be red */
.parent:hover a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.parent a:hover,
.parent a:hover ~ a {
  text-decoration: none;
}`

Comment: Here is your HTML:
`<div class="parent">
  <a href=#>Link 1</a>
  <a href=#>Link 2</a>
  <a href=#>Link 3</a>
  <a href=#>Link 4</a>
  <a href=#>Link 5</a>
</div>`

Comment: This was my source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector. It looks like there's really no "previous sibling" selector, but the second response in this thread has a pretty good response.

Answer (score -1):

if you know JavaScript you can use mouse events to do it with help of dom

Comment: I don't know much about JS so I'm a bit lost with it